# SwiftUI: Prevent .onHover on overlapping views

Tags: ios, macos, swiftui

I have two views that both react to `.onHover` overlapping in a `ZStack`. Currently the effect is triggered in the blue view even if it is overlapped by the red view (see video). How can I make sure that only the view at the top of the `ZStack` will react to `.onHover`, so that the blue view will not change when the overlapping part of the red view is hovered?

[image]

Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RectangleView(color: .blue)
                .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
            RectangleView(color: .red)
                .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                .offset(x: -150)
        }
        .frame(width: 600, height: 400)
    }
}

struct RectangleView: View {
    @State var hover = false
    var color: Color

    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(color)
            .overlay(hover ? Color.white.opacity(0.3) : Color.clear)
            .onHover { isHovering in
                if isHovering {
                    hover = true
                } else {
                    hover = false
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a side note… `hover = isHovering` will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way that is felixaeble with deferent scenario:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            
            RectangleView(color: .blue, index: 0)
                .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
            
            RectangleView(color: .red, index: 1)
                .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                .offset(x: -150)
            
            RectangleView(color: .black, index: 2)
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                .offset(x: -150)
            
            RectangleView(color: .green, index: 3)
                .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                .offset(x: 150, y: 150)
            
        }
        .frame(width: 600, height: 600)
    }
}

struct RectangleView: View {
    let color: Color
    let index: Int
    @StateObject var observableHoveringObject: ObservableHoveringObject = ObservableHoveringObject.shared
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(color)
            .overlay(observableHoveringObject.isHovering(index: index) ? Color.white.opacity(0.3) : Color.clear)
            .onHover { hoverValue in
                observableHoveringObject.sign(index, hoverValue: hoverValue)
            }
    }
}


class ObservableHoveringObject: ObservableObject {
    
    static let shared: ObservableHoveringObject = ObservableHoveringObject()
    
    @Published var activeHoveringIndex: Int? = nil
    
    
    func isHovering(index: Int) -> Bool {
        return index == activeHoveringIndex
    }
    
    private func exited(_ index: Int) { setCollection.remove(index) }
    
    private func entered(_ index: Int) { isHoveringTrafficLightFunction(index: index) }
    
    func sign(_ index: Int, hoverValue: Bool) {
        if (hoverValue) { entered(index) }
        else { exited(index) }
    }
    
    private var setCollection: Set<Int> = Set<Int>() {
        
        didSet {
            
            let filteredSet: Set<Int>.Element? = setCollection.max(by: { (lhs, rhs) in
                if (lhs < rhs) { return true }
                else { return false }
            })
            
            if let unwrappedValue: Int = filteredSet { activeHoveringIndex = unwrappedValue }
            else { activeHoveringIndex = nil }
            
        }
        
    }
    
    private func isHoveringTrafficLightFunction(index: Int) {
        
        if let unwrappedActiveHoveringIndex: Int = activeHoveringIndex {
            
            setCollection.insert(index)
            
            if (index >= unwrappedActiveHoveringIndex) { activeHoveringIndex = index }
            
        }
        else {
            activeHoveringIndex = index
            setCollection.insert(index)
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Now, when you run the asker's codes, it will works fine, only one color will be lighted.

But I met the same question if you put your view in a List, for example:

```swift
ZStack {
    List {
        RectangleView(color: .blue)
            .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
    }
    .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
    RectangleView(color: .red)
        .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
        .offset(x: -150)
}
.frame(width: 600, height: 400)
```

I got the same result with the asker's. Here is the way to solve it.

```swift
struct MyList<T: View>: View {
    
    @State private var isHover = false
    
    private var content: () -> T
    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> T) {
        self.content = content
    }
    var body: some View {
        List {
            content()
                .allowsHitTesting(isHover)
        }
        .onHover {
            isHover = $0
        }
    }
}
```

Hover action of View in List works incorrectly, but List itself works well. Just ignore all the actions of the views in List if List is not in hover state.

Hope it helps.

Xcode Version: 15.0